# Post Two Select with Multiple Select

Tags: php, html

For example I have HTML like this

```
<select name="something[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

and inside my form I can add these select muliple time dynamic by javascript
so it become

```
 <!-- Control 1 -->
 <select name="something[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
 <!-- Control 2 -->
   <select name="something[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

and then on Control 1 I choose "1" , on Control 2 I choose "1&2" .
what I get from PHP post is something like this

```
array("1","2")
```

what I want to get is :

```
array(
 array("1"),
 array("1","2")
)
```

Please help!!!

Comment: try name="something[0][]" name="something[1][]"

Comment: Having form controls with the same name will/can cause problems. I suggest rename the second one to a slightly different name so you know which control you are processing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name `something[]` to both of the inputs. So it will be confusing to catch the data when it is submitted (specially when you have the same values in both). Therefore I think it is better to use two different names `something_1[]` and `something_2[]` for the two inputs. **(the code is not in a proper standard. I was just trying to address the issue)**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="GET">
     <!-- Control 1 -->
 <select name="something_1[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
 <!-- Control 2 -->
 <select name="something_2[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ([something_1] => Array([0] => 1) [something_2] => Array([0] => 1 [1] => 2))
```

> Another apporach

As @alamnaryab mentioned in his comment, you can use that approach too. It will serve the two arrays as separate arrays.

```
print_r($_GET['something[0][]']);
print_r($_GET['something[1][]']);
```